# Azure Net core : The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process

Tags: azure, .net-core, identityserver4

I deployed my .net core application in azure. After deployment, I have faced this issue sometimes **"The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process."**.

Its working fine when debug locally. Kindly help me how to fix this issue.

Comment: Are you using any external libraries that might not be available in your Azure environment? Or stuff like GDI? Please provide some more information as this isn't enough to help you. Have a look how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Using IdentityServer4, I generated the Token and refresh the token. Error occured in the Refresh token functionality. This error occurs frequently in azure environment. In local, it works fine. Is it okay??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/664) on Github. Apparently this can occur when you're trying to get a specific certificate that IdentityServer can't find.

> I think I was failing to retrieve a certificate and this was causing a sudden stop when it was required.

Please take a look at (the somewhat dated) article [Using Certificates in Azure Websites Applications](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/)

In short:

1. Upload the certificate (for instance to the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com))
2. Add app setting
   Adding an app setting named WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES with its value set to the thumbprint of the certificate will make it accessible to your web application.
3. Access the certificate:

```
X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
                           X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                           “<YOUR_CERT_THUMBPRINT_HERE>”,
                           false);
// Get the first cert with the thumbprint
if (certCollection.Count > 0)
{
  X509Certificate2 cert = certCollection[0];
  // Use certificate
}
```