# CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process

Tags: solr, azure-web-app-service, sitecore

We have hosted our SOLR service in our Azure Pass environment. We are getting the below error intermittently.

**The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.**

I have restarted the service and it is working fine. BUt it is coming again and again.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to [Apache Solr](https://solr.apache.org), I'm not to familiar with it's setup. But have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54286447/10987310) which is regarding certificate loading. Your app may be trying to use an invalid cert.